# Which if any of these USB connectors on the PCB for this screen, would be for power?

Tags: power, pcb

I have two screens/displays. (If I turned the PCBs in the pic over, you'd see they have screens on the other side).

Screen A, is the one on the bottom. That one I know which one is Power, because it is labelled in little white writing on the PCB, "Power". The word power in little white writing on the PCB should be visible in the picture.

Screen B, is on the top. Both those USB connectors in little white writing are labelled Touch.

I'm wondering if it's possible to determine looking at the PCB, whether

A) The situation with Screen B, is it has no Power connector, in which case it's very faulty. And literally has two USB connectors for "Touch" and is missing a power connector.

or

B) The situation with Screen B, is that one of the USB connectors has been mislabelled as Touch. So one of the USB connectors is Power I don't know which.. Maybe it's possible to identify it from the picture?

[image]

Comment: Plug a cable into each port and see which one makes it power on.

Comment: @TypeIA it's that a very dangerous terrible idea, because plugging power into the wrong port could break a device.  So it'd be a bad idea to plug a power cable into the usb connector not marked power, unless sure that it  a usb connector intended for power!

Comment: No. USB cables always supply 5 V on VBUS even if it's not used as a power source by the device.

Comment: @TypeIA Well, technically USB cables don't supply.  One end of the USB cable is plugged into a USB connector that is supplying.  So, what happens if the USB connector on the screen, that I connect the USB cable to, will supply. Then I have connected a supply to a supply.  And that'd be bad wouldn't it?

Comment: How could your board supply anything if it doesn't have power?

Comment: @Mat good point.. still though , by plugging a cable carrying 5V, into a USB connector that, (fine, it isn't supplying 5V), but is a connector that isn't designed to take 5V, maybe that's not good for it? i.e. suppose a connector on the device is designed to output 5V but isn't outputting 5V 'cos no power is going to the device. That connector still isn't meant to take 5V as input! So i'm not sure it is safe to plug 5V into it

Comment: USB is standardized for a reason. And since there's multiple circuits on both boards that look like voltage regulators, there might be several options.

Comment: @Mat similarly.. suppose i had a power supply, unplugged it. Then I took another power supply and fed power into it.  Is the power supply that is unplugged and has power being fed into it, going to be ok?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, it's a very bad idea to place PCBs on top of a bloody fleece(?) blanket. If the boards were working before, well congrats... that may no longer be the case.

Comment: You're overthinking this. It's perfectly safe, just try it. Those are micro USB connectors and will expect 5 V on VBUS. There are plenty of resources here and elsewhere on the web where you can research USB in more detail.

Comment: @TypeIA  is it the case that,  USB-A outputs 5V, USB-B expects 5V.   USB-C expects 5V.  Micro USB-B expects 5V?   So connecting A to non-A, is thus always safe. And A-A is trouble? And that's why this is safe? (and thus both those connectors expect 5V)

Comment: @barlop USB-C is a more complicated matter because it's symmetric; an electrical handshaking is done using dedicated CC pins to establish capabilities and roles. (Thanks to this handshaking, all connection possibilities - even charger-to-charger - are safe, so long as the devices are spec-compliant.) Otherwise you're basically right. USB-OTG slightly muddies the water but it's still safe even if this were an OTG device, which it isn't. Keep in mind USB was designed with general consumers in mind, where it's 100% certain people will occasionally plug things in incorrectly.

Comment: @TypeIA well, if USB is designed to cater for people plugging things in incorrectly, then what if you have a "phone charger" that is a battery.  With a USB-A connector on it and a USB-B connector on it. Do you think that if somebody connected that phone charger to a computer with a USB-A USB-A cable, it'd be fine because USB deals with it being plugged wrongly like that?

Comment: USB A-to-A cables are not permitted by the spec. Let's not play "what if" games. If you _try_, yes, you can damage stuff. This is a wild tangent from your question and situation. This is my last comment.

Answer (score 0):

Plugging in a power source into either USB connector should not damage anything, even if one connector is an “output”. Internally those boards likely either connect VBUS together between the connectors, or use a power switch that is protected from current back flow. So nothing will be damaged. You are trying to be careful but if I got such screens and they got damaged by plugging in a USB power source as everyone expects, I’d toss them. They would be junk it’s not worth wasting time on.